# Error 404 from Github using Ueberauth

Tags: oauth, elixir, phoenix-framework, github-api, ueberauth

The page I am redirected to:

[image: the page I am redirected to]

The link looks like this:

https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%2Cpublic_repo

Output from my terminal, seems like it is code `302`

[image: Output from my terminal, seems like it is code <code>302</code>]

I am using Ueberauth, Elixir, Phoenix.

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was.

I had problem that I just copy-pasted code from ueberauth_github and replaced the `GITHUB_CLIENT_ID` and `GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET` with my own.
[image: config :ueberauth]

There is a problem that it calls `System.get_env`. So I changed it to:

[image]

Now it works.

Comment: I believe the client_id and client_secret are meant to be private and they cannot be shared. I would recommend you to ask for a new secret on GitHub UI, if possible, and remove the image from here. :)

Comment: It was just for learning and development purposes, thanks for suggestions :) in production I will hide it somehow, anyway, could you recommend me some nice way to do that, or some nice pattern in real world to hide those data?

Answer (score 0):

When you create variables in .env you need to source that too so it will work in your project directory by running the following command in terminal

```
source .env
```

if .env is in any folder e.g config/.env then

```
source config/.env
```

I had a same issue with little research its fixed with this command.